# Processing double post request with rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, mongoid

In the html, I have 2 divs with .column class. So, I've created an each loop to serialize the data for each .column div.

```
// item.js
$('.column').each(function(){
  update: $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'));
});
```

Examples are `item[]=1&item[]=5&item[]=4` and `item[]=2&item[]=3`. These parameters will be sent to the rails controller, sort via POST.

While in the rails controller

```
def sort
  params[:item].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Item.where(_id: id.last).update(position: index+1)
    #Item.where(_id: id.last).update(position: index+4)
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```

Q: How to process the post parameters in a DRY way? For the first request (`item[]=1&item[]=5&item[]=4`), I want to update the database (mongoid) with `position: index+1`, while second request I want it to be updated with `position: index+4`. Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider adding a new parameter (e.g. 'request_type') or having two different actions?

Comment: it works, but would it be ugly?

Comment: To be honest what you're doing looks a bit ugly. :) You could also send the increment as a parameter (1 or 4).

Comment: I don't know how to send parameters from jQuery to controller. Can you show me as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the increment value as a parameter in your forms. In your view, just add a new hidden tag in inside your `form` tag (assuming you're using ERB):

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :increment, [INCREMENT_VALUE] %>
```

and edit your `sort` method to look something like

```
def sort
  params[:item].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Item.where(_id: id.last).update(position: index+1 + params[:increment].to_i)
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```